# I am new to camel framework , I tried a program to copy a file from one directory to another but while running the program I got the following error

Tags: java, apache-camel

Error:(3, 24) java: /C:/Users/AMIT/IdeaProjects/learncamel/src/main/java/com/learnCamel/copyfile.java:3: cannot access org.apache.camel.CamelContext
bad class file: jar:///C:/Users/AMIT/.m2/repository/org/apache/camel/camel-api/3.1.0/camel-api-3.1.0.jar!/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.class from ZipFileObject
class file has wrong version 52.0, should be 50.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

I am new to Camel and java so I am not sure how to correct it. If anyone can help I would be thankful.

Comment: Can you add your code and pom.xml too?

Comment: Hey thanks @SneharghyaPathak , I just got the issue solved ,  actually the problem was with java versions. the runtime version was 1.8 and the code was compiling with 1.6.

Comment: @AmitKumar can you please than answer your own question, because otherwise this question will remain unresolved? You can see how here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I resolved this issue. The problem was that my runtime java was version 1.6 and the compiler was using version 1.8 for compiling so that's why it was showing error.